# Implementing Abstract class

Tags: python, object-oriented, inheritance

I used Pythons source code/documentation/textbook to come up with an abstract class and following subclasses.

**My requirements are:**

- Domestic students don't require documentation
- International student do require documentation (passports, etc..)

  ```
  from abc import ABCMeta

  class Student(metaclass=ABCMeta):

      def __init__(self, id, firstname, lastname):
          self.__id = id
          self.__firstname = firstname
          self.__lastname = lastname

      @property
      def iden(self):
          return self.__id

      @property
      def first_name(self):
          return self.__firstname

      @property
      def last_name(self):
          return self.__lastname
  ```

International Subclass:

```
from Student import Student
from copy import deepcopy


class International(Student):
    def __init__(self, iden, firstname, lastname, docuemnts):
        super().__init__(iden, firstname, lastname)

        self.__documents = deepcopy(docuemnts)
        self.__type_of_student = "International"

    @property
    def international_documents(self):
        return deepcopy(self.__documents)
```

Domestic Subclass:

```
from Student import Student


class Domestic(Student):

    def __init__(self, iden, firstname, lastname):
        super().__init__(iden, firstname, lastname)

        self.__type_of_student = "Domestic"

    @property
    def student_type(self):
        return self.__type_of_student
```

Have I constructed and implementation the `abstract` `class` correctly?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

- How do you tell what the student type is, without erroring on both `International` and `Domestic`?

  With your current code, you'd have to do something like:

  ```
  if hasattr(student, 'student_type'):
      student_type = student.student_type()
  else:
      student_type = None
  ```

  What makes this worse, is you assume `None` to be `International`.
- Why can't Domestic students have `international_documents`?

  In your requirements you state:

  > - Domestic students don't require documentation
  > - International student do require documentation (passports, etc..)
- Why should these be separate classes?
- Your name mangled variables make your code longer, and generally more horrible to read.
  Instead you could make them just normal properties.

  However, since they are unsetable, you may want to use a `namedtuple` instead.

And so I'd use something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from Enum import enum

class StudentType(Enum):
    INTERNATIONAL = 'international'
    DOMESTIC = 'domestic'

Student = namedtuple('Student', 'id first_name last_name type documents')

s1 = Student(0, 'John', 'Doe', StudentType.INTERNATIONAL, [...])
s2 = Student(1, 'Eva', 'Smith', StudentType.DOMESTIC, [])
```

Comment: Reading your comments made me realize I screwed up when I posted this code. The abstract class is supposed to contain `StudentType`, allow me to correct this.

Comment: Given that domestic can't have documents, I needed a way for client not to pass documents. I don't want to trust the client code too much, if I used to `namedtuple`, there is nothing stopping client code from pass documents to domestic.

Comment: @S.R. Yes, however what if a domestic needs documents linked to their account? Also your code doesn't make it so that internationals need documents, they can pass an empty list of documents. You can also always subclass `Student` so that it's created with the validation you need.